# Can we self-host a network like tor with tor source code?

Tags: source-code

Can we use tor source code for running a network like tor ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tor is licensed under a [3-clause BSD license](https://github.com/torproject/tor/blob/main/LICENSE). That means that you can do what you want with it including selling it as long as you follow the terms of the license. Here is a guide to setting up your own [tor network](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#PrivateTorNetwork).

Answer (score 0):

yes, and there're a lot of scripts in launching it in Docker'ed environment. No problems here: even the Directories are using the **very same** code base, just custom `torrc` configs